# Python Auto page-up/down Pdf viewer

Tags: python, bash, pdf, raspberry-pi

I am trying to display few pdf pages on my raspberry pi 4.
The goal is:

1. Display the pdf
2. "Page Down" every X seconds
3. Stop the program after N pages

Do you know which pdf viewer can do that?
Actually, I just split the PDF file by page and open (and close) one page at once.
The result is not good (as expected): each time I close one page, the desktop is shown and it is not ok.

```
    import subprocess
    import time

    offsetChar = 48
    waitTime = 2
    filePath = '/home/pi/Desktop/pdfToRead/1_nameFile.pdf'
    numberOfPages = 9

    for k in range (1,numberOfPages):
        str1 = filePath
        list1 = list(str1)
        list1[27] = chr(offsetChar+k)
        str1 = ''.join(list1)
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['xpdf', '-fullscreen', str1])
        time.sleep(waitTime)
        proc.terminate()
```

What I have already and not successfully found

- Simulate "page down" keyboard input for proc.communicate
- Search other pdf viewer with bash control while running

Have you any idea to simulate a "page down" keyboard input into an already displayed pdf?

EDIT:
The solution with pynput could be OK but it is not working for me. The mouse.press and keyboard.press append only when the PDF is no more fullscreen. It is like pynput does not act on the PDF windows.

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
import time
import subprocess

mouse = MouseController()
keyboard = KeyboardController()

filePath = '/home/pi/Desktop/pdfToRead/nameFile.pdf'

proc = subprocess.Popen(['xpdf', '-fullscreen', filePath])

mouse.press(Button.left) ## try to click on the PDF
mouse.release(Button.left)

keyboard.press(Key.page_down)
keyboard.release(Key.page_down)
```

Comment: maybe you should use `pyautogui` or `pynput` to control keyboard. It sends key directly to active window - without using `proc.communicate`. Besides  `proc.communicate` can send only `ASCII` chars, not special keys. You have to ask system (Windows, Linux, Mac) to send special keys to windows.

Comment: or maybe you should use modules like `python-poppler` to directly render PDF.